# Joomla! Yoothemes Carousel refuses to load more than 4 slides

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, carousel

I started up a forum topic here: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=472&t=716885 but have had no reply. I have a Joomla! 1.5 site where Yootheme Carousel module is used to rotate banner images. I have added six and in the Yootheme carousel settings I have adjusted the amount of slides to load. But somehow it keeps on loading the initial ones added a few years ago and not the new ones. I do not see any 404 errors and I do believe the file rights are fine. Even with `CHMOD 755` only the initial older four are loaded, but not the final two. Any ideas?

**Update I**
Cache for the slider is turned off and after reloading the two extra images were still not loaded. Wonder if the module stores the new value or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2T4LggLnjpU) with the missing step. Was not enought to add the image to media/artboard/large. I also had to integrate it into an article with section Artboard and Category  large.